# Why can't you use 'Just' syntax without 'let..in' block in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, option-type

I have a few questions regarding the `Just` syntax in Haskell.

When question arose when I was experimenting with different ways to write a function to calculate [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Consider the function:

```
binom :: Integer -> Integer -> Maybe Integer
binom n k | n < k     = Nothing
binom n k | k == 0    = Just 1
binom n k | n == k    = Just 1
binom n k | otherwise = let 
                          Just x = (binom (n-1) (k-1))
                          Just y = (binom (n-1) k)
                        in
                          Just (x + y)
```

When I try to write the `otherwise` case without the `let..in` block without the let..in block like so:

```
binom n k | otherwise = (binom (n-1) (k-1)) + (binom (n-1) k)
```

I am faced with a compilation error `No instance for (Num (Maybe Integer)) arising from a use of ‘+’`. And so my first thought was that I was forgetting the `Just` syntax so I rewrote it as

```
binom n k | otherwise = Just ((binom (n-1) (k-1)) + (binom (n-1) k))
```

I am faced with an error even more confusing:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Maybe Integer’ with ‘Integer’
      Expected: Maybe Integer
        Actual: Maybe (Maybe Integer)
```

If I add `Just` before the binom calls, the error just compounds:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Maybe (Maybe Integer)’ with ‘Integer’
      Expected: Maybe Integer
        Actual: Maybe (Maybe (Maybe Integer))
```

Furthermore, if I write:

```
Just x = binom 3 2
y = binom 3 2
```

`x` will have the value `3` and `y` will have the value `Just 3`.

So my questions are:

1. Why does the syntax requite the `let..in` block to compile properly?
2. In the function, why does `Just` add the `Maybe` type when I don't use `let..in`?
3. Contrarily, why does using `Just` outside of the function remove the `Just` from the value if it's type is `Just :: a -> Maybe a`

Bonus question, but unrelated:

- When I declare the function without the type the compiler infers the type `binom :: (Ord a1, Num a2, Num a1) => a1 -> a1 -> Maybe a2`. Now I mostly understand what is happening here, but I don't see why `a1` has two types.

Comment: The "assignment" `Just x = ...` matches `...` against `Just x`, binding `x` to the wrapped value if the match succeeds. It doesn't apply `Just` to anything.

Comment: Yeah, I was very confused about that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MichaelLitchard Yeah I realized that my question was a bit unorganized and confusing because I didn’t understand enough about Just and Maybe to form the right question. Luckily the answerers knew how to interpret my question though. I wondered if it would be better to delete the question entirely, but I’m not too active on here so I didn’t know if it would be appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question demonstrates a few ways you may have got confused about what is going on.

Firstly, `Just` is not any kind of syntax - it's just a data constructor (and therefore also a function) provided by the standard library. The reasons your failing attempts didn't compile are therefore not due to any syntax mishaps (the compiler would report a "parse error" in this case), but - as it actually reports - type errors. In other words the compiler is able to parse the code to make sense of it, but then when checking the types, realises something is up.

So to expand on your failing attempts, #1 was this:

```
binom n k | otherwise = Just ((binom (n-1) (k-1)) + (binom (n-1) k))
```

for which the reported error was

```
No instance for (Num (Maybe Integer)) arising from a use of ‘+’
```

This is because you were trying to add the results of 2 calls to `binom` - which according to your type declaration, are values of type `Maybe Integer`. And Haskell doesn't by default know how to add two `Maybe Integer` values (what would `Just 2 + Nothing` be?), so this doesn't work. You would need to - as you eventually do with your successful attempt - unwrap the underlying Integer values (assuming they exist! I'll come back to this later), add those up, and then wrap the resulting sum in a `Just`.

I won't dwell on the other failing attempts, but hopefully you can see that, in various ways, the types also fail to match up here too, in the ways described by the compiler. In Haskell you really have to understand the types, and just flinging various bits of syntax and function calls about in the wild hope that the thing will finally compile is a recipe for frustration and lack of success!

So to your explicit questions:

> Why does the syntax requite the let..in block to compile properly?

It doesn't. It just needs the types to match everywhere. The version you ended up with:

```
let 
  Just x = (binom (n-1) (k-1))
  Just y = (binom (n-1) k)
in
  Just (x + y)
```

is fine (from the type-checking point of view, anyway!) because you're doing as I previously described - extracting the underlying values from the `Just` wrapper (these are `x` and `y`), adding them up and rewrapping them.

But this approach is flawed. For one thing, it's boilerplate - a lot of code to write and try to understand if you're seeing it for the first time, when the underlying pattern is really simple: "unwrap the values, add them together, then rewrap". So there should be a simpler, more understandable, way to do this. And there is, using the methods of the Applicative typeclass - of which the `Maybe` type is a member.

Experienced Haskellers would write the above in one of two ways. Either:

```
binom n k | otherwise = liftA2 (+) (binom (n-1) (k-1)) (binom (n-1) k)
```

or

```
binom n k | otherwise = (+) <$> binom (n-1) (k-1) <*> binom (n-1) k
```

(the latter being in what is called the "applicative style" - if you're unfamiliar with Applicative functors there's a great introduction in Learn You a Haskell [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids). )

And there's another advantage of doing this compared to your way, besides the avoidance of boilerplate code. Your pattern matches in the `let... in` expression *assume* that the results of `binom (n-1) (k-1)` and so on are of the form `Just x`. But they could also be `Nothing` - in which case your program will crash at runtime! And exactly this will indeed happen in your case, as @chepner describes in his answer.

Using `liftA2` or `<*>` will, due to how the Applicative instance is implemented for `Maybe`, avoid a crash by simply giving you `Nothing` as soon as one of the things you're trying to add is Nothing. (And this in turn means your function will always return `Nothing` - I'll leave it to you to figure out how to fix it!)

I'm not sure I really understand your questions #2 and #3, so I won't address those directly - but I hope this has given you some increased understanding of how to work with `Maybe` in Haskell. Finally for your last question, although it's quite unrelated: "I don't see why a1 has two types" - it doesn't. `a1` denotes a single type, because it's a single type variable. You're presumably referring to the fact it has two *constraints* - here `Ord a1` and `Num a1`. `Ord` and `Num` here are typeclasses - like Applicative is that I mentioned earlier (albeit Ord and Num are simpler typeclasses). If you don't know what a typeclass is I recommend reading an introductory source, like Learn You a Haskell, before continuing much further with the language - but in short it's a bit like an interface, saying that the type must implement certain functions. Concretely, `Ord` says the type must implement order comparisons - you need that here because you've used the `<` operator - while `Num` says you can do numeric things with it, like addition. So that type signature just makes explicit what is implicit in your function definition - the values you use this function on must be of a type that implements both order comparison and numeric operations.

Comment: I think you inadvertently answered questions 2 and 3. What I'm gathering here is that `Just` is actually acting on the values: either wrapping them or unwrapping them, as you put it. In the case of my binom function, it's doing both, the let just happens to be a way of creating to variables that Just can use to unwrap the values returned from binom so you can add them and then in the in clause it wraps the sum so it can be returned by binom since it requires a `Maybe` value. And `let..in` and `Just` are unrelated and one doesn't need the other to work properly.

Comment: Thanks - it sounds like you've largely got it. So one thing I didn't say, because I hadn't realised how it might be posiblly confusing you, is that data constructors like `Just`, while they are functions, aren't "just" functions. The main other thing they do is that they can be used in pattern matching, which is what happens in your `let` clauses here: `let Just x = something` means essentially to "take apart" the `something` value and, assuming it's of the form `Just y`, assign `x` to whatever `y` is.

Comment: I am confused though why my solution will crash at runtime. Because of the guards in place, it looks like in the case of `binom (n-1) (k-1)`, if it reaches that then `n` is already greater than `k` and will consistently be and before `n` can reach `0`, `k` will therefore it will always return 1 before it can return Nothing. Are you and @chepner saying that the let..in clause will fail on it's own?

Comment: Also thanks for all your help! I like the distinction you made and the example on how to avoid the boilerplate code. Tbh, I didn't even think my code was boilerplate code, but I understand now what you mean.

Comment: @kohai the problem in the recursive definion isn't the `binom (n-1) (k-1)` part, it's the other one `binom (n-1) k`. No matter what `n` and `k` are, eventually this will always reach a point where `n` is less than `k`, because `n` is reducing each time you recurse, while `k` is not. I confess I haven't tried to compile your code and run the function, but I'd be amazed if it doesn't produce `Nothing` in many simple cases where it should give a sensible result. (That's in the version I offered - with your original one I expect it to simply crash.)

Comment: Oh duh, I know exactly what you're saying now. I mean, as far as I'm aware it compiles and runs as expected and without runtime errors. Regardless it has been made clear that I need to avoid code like this in the future. So it's not a solution that I'm going to rely on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
binom n k | otherwise = (binom (n-1) (k-1)) + (binom (n-1) k)
```

You can't add two `Maybe` values, but you can make use of the `Functor` instance to add the values already wrapped in `Just`.

```
binom n k | otherwise = fmap (+) (binom (n-1) (k-1)) (binom (n-1) k)
```

This doesn't quite work, as eventually the recursive calls will return `Nothing`, and `fmap (+) x y == Nothing` if either `x` or `y` is `Nothing`. The solution is to treat two different occurrences of `n < k` differently.

1. An "initial" use can return `Nothing`
2. A "recursive" use can simply return 0, since `x + 0 == x`.

`binom` will be implemented in terms of a helper that is guaranteed to receive arguments such that `n >= k`.

```
binom :: Integer -> Integer -> Maybe Integer
binom n k | n < k     = Nothing
          | otherwise = Just (binom' n k)
  where binom' n 0 = 1
        binom' n k | n == k = 1
                   | otherwise = binom' (n-1) (k-1) + binom' (n-1) k
```

Comment: Your solution is super helpful in understanding what is really going on with the function. However, I'm confused do you mean the fmap solution will not work properly or both the fmap and my solution will not work? Are you saying that the `let..in` clause is not thorough enough on it's own to be a solution or the entirety of my pattern matching is not exhaustive enough to protect against an unintentional `Nothing` value arising?

Comment: It's not. If `binom` returns `Nothing`, then `Just x = binom ...` fails to match, rather than binding `x` to 0. That's why I split the definition into two parts: one where `binom n k` is undefined when `n < k`, and one where `n >= k` is guaranteed.

Comment: (Strictly speaking, `binom'` is just as undefined when `n < k`. But `binom` only calls `binom'` when `n >= k`, and the recursive maintain that invariant: `n >= k` implies both `n - 1 >= k -1` and `n-1 >= k`.)

Answer (score 1):

This question has received excellent answers. However, I think it is worth mentioning that you can also use a **monadic do construct**, like the one normally used for the “main program” of a Haskell application.

The main program generally uses a *do* construct within the IO monad. Here, you would use a *do* construct within the `Maybe` monad.

Your `binom` function can be modified like this:

```
binom :: Integer -> Integer -> Maybe Integer
binom n k | n < 0     = Nothing  -- added for completeness
binom n k | k < 0     = Nothing  -- added for completeness
binom n k | n < k     = Nothing
binom n k | k == 0    = Just 1
binom n k | n == k    = Just 1
binom n k | otherwise = do  -- monadic do construct, within the Maybe monad
                            x <- (binom (n-1) (k-1))
                            y <- (binom (n-1) k)
                            return (x+y)

main :: IO ()
main = do  -- classic monadic do construct, within the IO monad
    putStrLn "Hello impure world !"
    putStrLn $ show (binom 6 3)
```

If a single `<-` extractor fails, the whole result is `Nothing`.

Please recall that in that context, `return`  is just an ordinary function, with type signature:

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

Unlike in most imperative languages, `return` is not a keyword, and is not part of control flow.

A key concern is that if you have *many* quantities that can become `Nothing`, the *do* construct looks more **scalable**, that is, it can become more readable than pattern matching or lift'ing functions. More details about using the `Maybe` monad in the online [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html) book.

Note that the Haskell library provides not only [`liftA2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2), as mentioned in Robin Zigmond's answer, but also other lift'ing functions up to [`lift6`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht-0.0.16/docs/Control-Applicative-HT.html#v:lift6).

### Interactive testing:

You can test the thing under the `ghci` interpreter, like this:

```
$ ghci
 GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> do { n1 <- (Just 3) ; n2 <- (Just 42); return (n1+n2) ; }
 Just 45
 λ> 
 λ> do { n1 <- (Just 3) ; n2 <- (Just 42); n3 <- Nothing ; return (n1+n2+n3) ; }
 Nothing
 λ>
```

The exact semantics depend on the sort of monad involved. If you use the list monad, you get a Cartesian product of the lists you're extracting from:

```
 λ> 
 λ> do { n1 <- [1,2,3] ; n2 <- [7,8,9];  return (n1,n2) ; }
 [(1,7),(1,8),(1,9),(2,7),(2,8),(2,9),(3,7),(3,8),(3,9)]
 λ>
```

Comment: This is a little beyond my expertise of Haskell currently but I appreciate your answer nonetheless. Monads are still somewhat nuanced and obscure to me, but your answer does offer some intuition that I will be able to use later on. Thanks for your help!